# Input field in not Editing..How to write onchange function for input field in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Im sending props value to the input field.When im trying to edit the 
    field it is not editing..How to write onchange handle function.Can anyone 
    explain briefly about controlled and uncontrolled inputs

```
handleUserInput = (e) => {
//what to do here in order to edit the input field
}
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="info">
                <label className="label">Store Name</label>
                <input type="text" 
                    ref="storename"                                                                                       
                    className="form-control"                                                                                       
                    value={this.props.storeName}                                                                                       
                    placeholder="Store Name"                                                                                                                                                                          
                    onChange={this.handleUserInput}                                                                                       
                    disabled={this.state.disabled}
                />                                
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
value={this.props.storeName}
```

to this (otherwise the value for input is always the same - the value received in props):

```
value={this.state.storeName}
```

and copy the props to the state in constructor(you should do that in constructor only if you are using props as an *initial* value):

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    storeName: props.storeName
  }
}
```

and

```
handleUserInput=(e)=>{
  this.setState({storeName: e.target.value});
}
```

Now we have made the input box a controlled element (with an initial value taking from the props though). If you are interested in controlled components more you can look in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), it isn't hard concept to grasp.

Comment: That is fine,But my problem is i have a dropdown with list of stores.when i select on store it will display the particular store details.in which input field is editable.In this case first time selectin working fyn.When im trying select another store the state is not updating.And in my console data is working perfect based on selection.Problem with my state

Comment: Thankyou so much,I have learnt new thing today about parent props and child state.